# apache userdir and permissions to write public_html (suPHP)?

Tags: apache2, php

I have set ubuntu 10.10 server with LAMP. I use USERDIR mod for apache, but when I install some CMS systems for user like Concrete5, I need to set `chmod 777` to some directorys to write data with CMS. Is it possible to add some permissions for apache, so that I don't need to use `chmod` command.

I have read something about suPHP. Is it good for this?

Comment: I would stay away from software/how to's that tells you to use `chmod 777`.

Comment: You'll find [that I recommend suPHP for this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/45496/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-files-to-a-website-on-a-lamp-server/46471#46471)

Comment: I used this one and it worked http://bibekshrestha.com.np/blogs/post/2009/08/18/setting-apache-userdir-and-suphp-ubuntu-810-server . Now I have only issues with reading generated file, for example .httaccess

Answer (score 1):

Just change all the files ownership under the `concrete5` directory to `www-data` or whatever user you are running:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data concrete5
```

[image]