# folder on /var/www is forbidden,why? (browser is showing forbidden message)

Tags: lamp, localhost

I installed LAMP, and created a file named `index.html`. This file is accessible via browser (`localhost/index.html`).

But when I moved my project folder to `/var/www/` , I can't browse any file via browser.

What to do now?

I tried to change the file permission, but I failed. Is it problem for file permission or server problem?

N.B.: I noticed a `403` forbidden message when I tried to browse `localhost/netsys/` (`netsys` is my project folder).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/45496/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-files-to-a-website-on-a-lamp-server

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of the folders that you have copied inside the www folder.
The default permissions should be set to drwxr-xr-x with root being the owner and root is the default group of the directory. Set it up in a recursive manner and it should solve your problem

You may run the command

> sudo chown -R *yourusername* /var/www/
>   sudo chmod -R 751 /var/www/

Comment: thanks a lot for reply..

But problem isn't Solved completely. After owning the var/www/, i can place files in this folder. But browser can't show any files. New placed files don't show any messages, but the files created before (index.html , testing.php) are showing the Forbidden message.

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.


What to do now? Please help.

Should i change anything in server configuration files?