# How do I create public html folder?

Tags: apache2, php, directory

I am a php programmer and new in ubuntu. Now I am using ubuntu 12.4 I need to create public html directory on my home directory for easy assess of php files. How can I create this public_html directory  on my home folder. And how it configure as a apache server for run php scripts?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! There is a more generalized post [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/45496/62483). Please take a look there and let us know if that post address your issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apache comes with userdir module which lets you use `/home/USER/public_html` as root directory.

You will access this public_html as `localhost/~USER/`

You may need to enable userdir, if not enabled, which is done by:

`sudo a2enmod`

By default Apache uses `/var/www` as document root.

Or you can create a virtualhost with your specific document root as well.

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html

Answer (score 2):

What I did for my case is created **public_html** directory in my home directory and then created symlink in `/var/www` to point to this *public_html* directory ([creating a symlink](http://lecturesnippets.com/creating-a-symbolic-link-to-the-www-directory-in-ubuntu/)).

In order to create a symlink you have to use the following command:

```
sudo ln -s /home/$USER/public_html /var/www
```

here `$USER` is your username.
For more details check the site mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. Now I find correct way for configure apache from stack overflow.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526742/how-can-i-make-a-public-html-folder-in-ubuntu

And from ask ubuntu

[Should I symlink my /var/www directory to my home?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45496/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-files-to-a-website-on-a-lamp-server)

Comment: Please mark your question as solved by picking one of the available answers.

Comment: I can't mark it as today. Stackoverflow says that "You can accept your own answer tomorrow". Then How can I?

Comment: Anti-cheating measure. You can select another answer in the meantime (you can change it later).