# Why is everything write protected?

Tags: permissions, apache2

I have searched and searched and can't find anything specific to my problem.

I am a Mac user, new to Ubuntu.  I wiped my HP notebook and installed 32-bit (no choice) Ubuntu.  Then I installed the LAMP server followed by phpMyAdmin.  My html folder was installed inside of root (/).  A shortcut to phpMyAdmin is inside of that.  Every time I try to do anything with web files, I get permission denied.  I created a file with Sublime Text, later double-clicked on it and when it opened in Gedit, I couldn't save changes because permission was denied.

I can understand needing permission to write to the root folder.  Why, then, is my www folder, something I would write to often, installed there?  It's useless to me there if I have to jump through hoops to do anything.  As a shot in the dark, am I supposed to create a www folder in my Home folder and map it to /var/www/html or vice versa?  If so, how do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I symlink my /var/www directory to my home?](http://askubuntu.com/q/45496) See also: [Whats the simplest way to edit and add files to “/var/www”?](http://askubuntu.com/q/19898), [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](http://askubuntu.com/q/46331), [Why shouldn't /var/www have chmod 777](http://askubuntu.com/q/20105), [What's the best way of handling permissions for apache2's user www-data in /var/www?](http://serverfault.com/q/6895), [What permissions should my website files/folders have on a Linux webserver?](http://serverfault.com/q/357108)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, regular users don't get permission to do many things to the file system outside their home directory. I think it's just to make sure that no one accidentally deletes something really important.

Anyways, about mapping, you can try this: create a folder with any name inside your home directory, open the terminal and use `sudo` to make a symbolic link in `/var/www` with the name `html` which would point to the folder in your home.

So for example, in your home, you can create a folder named `webdev`. Then open the terminal, and do the following:

```
cd /var/www
sudo mv html xyz
sudo ln -s ~/webdev html
```

And that should do it. Now you can manipulate files in the `webdev` folder inside your home.

Do make sure that the `webdev` folder in your home directory has proper permission to let other users at least access the contents. You can do this easily by right clicking on the `webdev` folder icon and going to Properties --> Permissions.